# DDD - Multiple Aggregates (Coupons And Purchases)

Tags: domain-driven-design, e-commerce, event-sourcing

I am building a DDD/ES system where an admin can generate coupon codes to be shared and used publicly by consumers.

Each coupon has a maximum discount amount that is "shared" by all users of the coupon. An example is "Coupon 123 grants 5% off up for every use up to a total of $100,000." The coupon automatically expires once that maximum amount is reached. The coupon may also have rules around which items are eligible for purchase with that coupon.

So far, I have the Coupon and Purchases as separate ARs. Questions?

1. How do I update the coupon remaining amount when a purchase is made without updating multiple aggregates in a single transaction? Since this is about money, it feels like eventual consistency could lead to lost revenue. Should a domain service be responsible for that or a Saga?
2. How do i validate that the items being purchased with the coupon are eligible? Do ask the Coupon AR in the command handler before continuing with the purchase: `couponAR.AreValidItems(request.PurchaseDetails)`
3. I would like to track how much of the coupon is allocated to each purchase? Should this be another AR (CouponUsageAR) or just an event on the Coupon AR (CouponUsed)?

Thanks

Comment: How busy do you think the `Coupon` AR will be? What's the risk of multiple users using the same coupon at the same time? This will determine whether or not it would be too costly to modify both in the same TX. Start simple & consistent and move towards eventual consistency as needed.

Comment: Thanks @plaix. It all depends on how successful the product is. If the product is successful, there could definitely be bursts of concurrent usage. Especially since the coupons are planned to have a very short expiration e.g. 24hrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice it is quite difficult to make a transaction (in the database sense) span multiple event streams.  A more usual way to do this would be to use the **saga pattern** with compensation events in the event that the saga fails, and use **correlation identifiers** in the events to match the different entities they occurred to.

For example you might have a saga which updates the coupon remaining and if that succeeds then goes on to perform the purchase.  Should the purchase fail the saga then needs to post a compensating event onto the coupon event stream to get it back to the state it was in at the start of the saga.

Have a look at the online video covering the saga pattern by Udi Dahan - or the documentation of that?

Answer (score 2):

On the subject of strong vs. eventual consistency, ask the domain expert (this is domain-driven design, after all) the question:

> which is worse: a coupon code delivering more discounts than its limit, or not being able to take an order?

If the answer is that they'd rather enforce the coupon limit and lose the sale, then strong consistency is called for.  If they'd rather take the order, then eventual consistency is called for.  It's worth noting that there's an easy way to prevent the coupon codes from ever breaching their limits: never have an order.

Comment: Thanks @Levi. I think i know what the answer to this question would be but you're right, I should confirm before building something to address it.